# Android - Sinch get push from own server with ManagedPush

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, sinch

I'm using Sinch for App-to-App messaging with ManagedPush set to true which states that

> NOTE: Using setSupportManagedPush(true) will register a token with Google Cloud Messaging using a Sender ID connected to Sinch, which will implicitly unregister your own token. You should not register any token with GCM if using Sinch push notifications.

Now beside push notifications from Sinch for Instant messaging, There are also other notifications i want to receive from my own server like general Ad etc for all users, I done some R&D but not able to figure out following

1. As Sinch registers GCM token itself so can i use the same token to send push notification from my own server?
2. If Answer for 1 is yes then how can i get Sinch registered token to send to my own server to receive notifications from my own server too along with one's sent via Sinch?
3. Or is there any way to get GCM token registered via Sinch from Google server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you already have your infrastrucutre to send push, I would use that instead of managed push. So instead of setSupportManagedPush(true) set setSupportPush(true) and then send the push to your server in onShouldSendPush event